# How to change color of UITextview UIDataDetectorTypeLink?

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextview, uicolor

1. I am passing some urls to the UITextView and they are detected using
   UIDataDetectorTypeLink. Now I'm in need to change the color of the
   link(url) to some uicolor. I have no idea on how to do this.

   Here is the code showing my attempt:

   ```
   [textview_Url setEditable:NO];
   [textview_Url setScrollEnabled:NO];
   [textview_Url setDataDetectorTypes:UIDataDetectorTypeLink];
   [textview_Url setText:web];
   ```

   It gives blue, and I want to change that color.
2. By UIDataDetectorTypeLink, a long press only asks conformation to
   redirect to the link. But I want to show some alert to ask
   confirmation if someone just touches it. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! Feel free to show us any code you have !

Comment: @AxelIsouard: ok
[textview_Url setEditable:NO];
    [textview_Url setScrollEnabled:NO];
    [textview_Url setDataDetectorTypes:UIDataDetectorTypeLink];
    [textview_Url setText:web];
but by default it gives blue color, i want to change the color it.. any idea????

Comment: Hi downvoter, Why DownVote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved**

I have used **globalTintColor** property of window,

like,

```
self.window.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
self.textView.linkTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};
```

Answer (score 2):

The better approach is    `self.textView.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];`
This change only links(phones) to red color.